# Simple hash of PIL image

Tags: python, hash, python-imaging-library

### Background

I want to store information of PIL images in a key-value store. For that, I hash the image and use the hash as a key.

### What I tried

I have been using the following code to compute the hash:

```
def hash(img):
   return hashlib.md5(img.tobytes()).hexdigest()
```

But it seems like this is not stable. I have not figured out why, but for the same image on different machines, I get different hashes.

### Question

Is there a simple way of **hashing images that only depends on the image itself** (not on timestamps, system architecture, etc.)?

Note that I do not need similar images to get a similar/same hash, as in [image hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998662/what-is-image-hashing-used-for). In fact, I want different images to have a different hash, e.g. changing the brightness of the image should change its hash.

Comment: Well, may be you can read the raw file using python built-in i/o (or use StringIO in IMG is available only in memory) and then calculate the hash, they would come out to be equal if the source is same.
check this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637085/different-image-data-from-the-same-source-with-pillow

Comment: You could try some perceptual hashes. There are a number of them such as block average hash as one simple one. I have some of these coded in a bash unix shell script with imagemagick called, phashes. You can find it at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. You can call it from  Python with subprocess module. Or perhaps someone else has one in Python. See for example http://blockhash.io

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing your goal is to perform image hashing in Python (which is much different than classic hashing, since byte representation of images is dependent on format, resolution and etc.)

One of the image hashing techniques would be **average hashing**. Make sure that this is not 100% accurate, but it works fine in most of the cases.

---

First we simplify the image by reducing its size and colors, reducing complexity of the image massively contributes to accuracy of comparison between other images:

**Reducing size:**

`img = img.resize((10, 10), Image.ANTIALIAS)`

**Reducing colors:**

`img = img.convert("L")`

Then, we find average pixel value of the image (which is obviously one of the main components of the average hashing):

```
pixel_data = list(img.getdata())
avg_pixel = sum(pixel_data)/len(pixel_data)
```

Finally hash is computed, we compare each pixel in the image to the average pixel value. If pixel is more than or equal to average pixel then we get 1, else it is 0. Then we convert these bits to base 16 representation:

```
bits = "".join(['1' if (px >= avg_pixel) else '0' for px in pixel_data])
hex_representation = str(hex(int(bits, 2)))[2:][::-1].upper()
```

If you want to compare this image to other images, you perform actions above, and find similarity between hexadecimal representation of **average hashed** images. You can use something as simple as [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) or more complex algorithms such as [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), [Ratcliff/Obershelp pattern recognition](http://Ratcliff/Obershelp%20pattern%20recognition) (SequenceMatcher), [Cosine Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) etc.

Comment: Amazing answer! A question. I understand that `[2:]` is used to remove `0x` at the beginning, but why `[:-1]` is used? Because 100 bits don't make a whole number of bytes? I plan to use img sized to 12*12, cuz 144 easily divides by 8.

Comment: @AivanF. I believe it was a mistake. It should be `[::-1]` perhaps due to byte order.

Comment: Author explicitley specified, that (s)he does **not** want to use [image hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998662/what-is-image-hashing-used-for) (what is btw. called "perceptual hashing"), and in contrary, author wants to use cryptographic hashing of image pixel data (= any differnece in image pixel data are supposed to result to different value of hash), ignoring other data stored in mimage file, like EXIF.

The main point of the question was that `PIL.Image.tobytes()` is supposed to return the **same** pixel data on any platform (CPU and/or OS) but it looks like it doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

Recognising what you say about timestamps, **ImageMagick** has exactly such a feature. First, an example.

Here I create two images with identical pixels but a timestamp at least 1 second different:

```
convert -size 600x100 gradient:magenta-cyan 1.png
sleep 2
convert -size 600x100 gradient:magenta-cyan 2.png
```

[image]

If I checksum them on macOS, it tells me they are different because of the embedded timestamp:

```
md5 -r [12].png

c7454aa225e3e368abeb5290b1d7a080 1.png
66cb4de0b315505de528fb338779d983 2.png
```

But if I checksum **just the pixels** with **ImageMagick**, (where `%#` is the pixel-wise checksum), it knows the pixels are identical and I get:

```
identify -format '%# - %f\n' 1.png 2.png
70680e2827ad671f3732c0e1c2e1d33acb957bc0d9e3a43094783b4049225ea5 - 1.png
70680e2827ad671f3732c0e1c2e1d33acb957bc0d9e3a43094783b4049225ea5 - 2.png
```

And, in fact, if I make a `TIFF` file with the same image contents, whether with Motorola or Intel byte order, or a NetPBM `PPM` file:

```
convert -size 600x100 gradient:magenta-cyan -define tiff:endian=msb 3motorola.tif
convert -size 600x100 gradient:magenta-cyan -define tiff:endian=lsb 3intel.tif
convert -size 600x100 gradient:magenta-cyan 3.ppm
```

**ImageMagick** knows they are the same, despite different file format, CPU architecture and timestamp,:

```
identify -format '%# - %f\n' 1.png 3.ppm 3{motorola,intel}.tif

70680e2827ad671f3732c0e1c2e1d33acb957bc0d9e3a43094783b4049225ea5 - 1.png
70680e2827ad671f3732c0e1c2e1d33acb957bc0d9e3a43094783b4049225ea5 - 3.ppm
70680e2827ad671f3732c0e1c2e1d33acb957bc0d9e3a43094783b4049225ea5 - 3motorola.tif
70680e2827ad671f3732c0e1c2e1d33acb957bc0d9e3a43094783b4049225ea5 - 3intel.tif
```

---

So, in answer to your question, I am suggesting you shell out to **ImageMagick** with the Python subprocess module and use **ImageMagick**.

Alternatively, you can use [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/) which is a ctypes binding to **ImageMagick**.

Comment: +1: By far the better answer to OP for addressing its requirements, by resorting to metadata-agnostic pixel-level hashing.